# Empty container is still occupying space in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display some children inside a column, they are properties of an object. However, one of the properties sometimes has a null value, so I want to make a validation. If the value of this property is null, I don't want to display anything. The answer it's not as easy as saying "just use a ternary operator and put an empty Container() instead". The container takes up space even if it is almost imperceptible. The same happens with Visibility. Empty Text, works the same. And so on. Here is my code:

```
          Container(
                    height: heightOfContext,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              child: FadeInImage(
                                placeholder: AssetImage(
                                    "assets/images/loading.png"),
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    products[index].file_url),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        ///HERE IS THE ISSUE, AT THE LAST CHILD

                        Expanded(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Modelo: ${products[index].description}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                    'Producto: ${products[index].colorName}'),
                                Text(
                                    'Color: ${products[index].price}'),
                                Text(
                                    'Categoría: ${products[index].categoryName}'),
                                productsSearchList[index].catalogue != null
                                    ? Text(
                                        'Catálogo: ${products[index].catalogue}')
                                    : Container(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options to fix this:

1. Did you try `SizedBox.shrink` or `Container(height: 0, width: 0)`?
2. The easiest way is to use an if statement within the column:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment:
        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
    Text(
        'Modelo: ${products[index].description}',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    Text(
        'Producto: ${products[index].colorName}'),
    Text(
        'Color: ${products[index].price}'),
    Text(
        'Categoría: ${products[index].categoryName}'),
    if(productsSearchList[index].catalogue != null) Text(
            'Catálogo: ${products[index].catalogue}')
    ],
),
```

Comment: Great! Simple solution and I didn't think about it. The if statement worked just perfectly. On the other hand SizedBox.shrink didn't work and neither container.

Comment: Glad I could help you out! - Could you approve my answer? Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a boolean variable mean
If data fetched correctly set that variable true and show your container if not ,means that variable is false then dont show the container.(with ?: operators)